# c# Check, if element already exist in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, button, flowlayoutpanel

I have a code that should create user elements in a flowLayoutPanel. But, each element should only exist once.

This is my code:

```
flowLayoutPanelUser.Controls.Clear();
foreach (Data a in AllData)
{
    if (a != null)
    {
        Button buttonHome = new Button();
        buttonHome.Text = a.User;
        buttonHome.Tag = a.User;

        flowLayoutPanelUser.Controls.Add(buttonHome);

        buttonHome.Click += new EventHandler(OpenUser_Click);
    }
}
```

`AllData` is the input.

I am looking for something like this:

```
if (!toolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>().Any(x => x.Text == a.Typ))
{

}
```

I had already been looking for a solution

Comment: You *can* search the UI component tree, but I would encourage you to do sorting/deduplication actions on your data structure (`AllData`) instead.  It'll be much faster and also continue working if you ever change UI technology, e.g. from WinForms to WPF

Comment: For example `var addedStrings = new HashSet<string>();` and then inside the loop `if (a != null && addedStrings.Add(a.User)) { /* not a duplicate, create the button */ }`